# Finding all points of continuity on $g(x,y)$

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

Given $g(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{x^2-y^2}{x-y},  & \text{if $x \neq y$}\\[2ex]
3x, & \text{if $x=y$}
\end{cases}$

Determine all points at which $g$ is continuous.

In order to establish continuity we must determine the limit of $g(x,y)$ as $(x,y)→0$. From what I have found so far,

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^2-y^2}{x-y}$ $=$ $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} (x+y)$ $=0$

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}3x = 3(0)=0$

Hence, $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}g(x,y) = 0$. However, I am unsure how to proceed from here as I can only safely assume $(0,0)$ is a point of continuity, but how do I go about finding the other points of continuity?

Comment: Start by noting that $g(x) = x+y$ if $x \neq y$.  From that point, it's probably easier to say where $g$ *isn't* continuous than to say where it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ **isn't** continuous at any point  on the line $y=x$ other than the origin, by the limit calculation:

$\lim_{(x,y)\to (x,x)}g(x,y)=2x$.

Because by the limit point definition of continuity,  we need the limit to be $g(x,x)=3x$.  This is only true at the origin.